# If $3x^2$ is the derivative of $x^3$, how can $f'(x)$ be a linear map?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have the function $f(x)=x^3$. The derivative is obviously $f'(x) = 3x^2$. But $3x^2$ is nonlinear since 
$$f'(3x) = 27x^2$$
$$3f'(x)  = 9x^2$$
Therefore this isn't a linear map.

Rudin defines the following 
$$f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + r(h)$$
where $r(h)$ is very small, and he says we can regard the derivative of $f$ at $x$ as the linear operator that maps 
$$h\mapsto f'(x)h$$

How does this make sense?

Comment: As you wrote, $f'$ is not linear but $h\mapsto f'(x)h$ is. The mistake you made is that you consider $x \mapsto f'(x)$ and not $h\mapsto f'(x)h$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$h\mapsto f'(x)h$ is a linear map **of** $\boldsymbol{h}$, not of $x$, which is only a fixed parameter in such questions. Isn't the tangent a straight line anyway?

Comment: So for any two functions $f$ and $g$, $(f+g)' = f' + g'$ and for any scalar $c$, $(cf)' = c(f')$.

Comment: @NealLawton That shows that *differentiation* is a linear map.  This question is asking about how the *derivative* is a linear map (it gives the best linear approximation to the rate of change at a point).

Answer (score 2):

It is linear at each point.  For example $f'(2)=12$.  So, the linear map this induces is $x\mapsto 12x$.